# Xcode 5 crashes when I click on auto layout(On)

Tags: ios7, autolayout, xcode5

When I'm viewing the storyboard, and click the auto layout check box, Xcode crashes and asks to send error report.  I clicked the auto layout to turn it off and must have saved it.  So now any time I open Xcode and turn it on, that's when it crashes.   Please help :(

EDIT:  Anybody?!?!  is this an xcode problem? Unique to me? It happens every time I click to turn it on...I can't make any progress   NOTHING!?!?

Edit:

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5A1413
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-3742/IBPlugin/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:670
Details:  Failed to compute auto layout status IBUIDatePicker, IBUILabel, IBUITableViewCell, and IBUITableViewCellContentView.

Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS Simulator. If you choose to file a crash report or radar for this issue, please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" and include their content in your crash report.

Exception name: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Exception reason: UITableView dataSource is not set

**I can't make any progress on my work.  Who should I talk to to fight this?

Comment: Can you show your crash log?

Comment: @bneely  Says that uitableview dataSource is not set, but I made sure that all tableviews have a ds.

Comment: If, as I understand it, this is coming from Xcode and not your program then it is an Xcode bug and you should report it.  How to circumvent it, I don't know -- first thing I'd try is a Clean, though that's a long shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just remade the entire tableviewcontroller that I changed the autolayout feature on(deleted it and started it from scratch).  did the trick. It must have been some xcode bug.